# IP based VirtualHost and Apache

Tags: apache, configuration, vhosts

I have this webserver that have an IP address xxx.xxx.xx.x, I also have a website I want to publish, but I do not have any domain for my website yet.

So in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I have this setting:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.x>
  ServerName xxx.xxx.xx.x
  DocumentRoot "C:\Sites\mysite"
</VirtualHost>
```

And since I dont have a domain I really want to use the IP address to reach my site, but I have tried this and it does not work. I guess you HAVE to set a server name in `ServerName` as the title says.

Are there any ways for me to make my website public through my IP address, if yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:\Sites\mysite
  ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to restart apache,

You may also need to add,

```
Listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the one website on this server, you don't need a virtual host.  Just set the DocumentRoot correctly and away you go.  Also make sure Apache is listening on all IP addresses (Listen 0.0.0.0:80.)

If that doesn't work for you, from your command prompt do:

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 80
GET /
```

and see what you get back - you should get your website's default page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I do run multiple sites and they work perfect since they have domains that are reffered to in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. But this one does not work since I dont have a domain, only a IP address.

Comment: It may be that you can't mix name-based virtual hosts and IP virtual-hosts unless you have an IP that the name-based hosts share, and another separate IP for your IP-based host.  Can you not just knock up a temporary DNS name on an existing domain - e.g. test.yoursite.com?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a programming question.

But anyway,

Set the VirtualHost to * rather than a specific IP address. I don't think you need the servername either then.

Comment: Thx for your reply, I know it is not a programming question but sill I think this is the correct forum to ask questions of this kind. I tried your solution:

<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\Sites\mysite"
</VirtualHost>

But still I dont get my site if I enter the IP of my server, and I have restarted Apache and checked that my server responds to ping.

Comment: @Martin - serverfault.com is the correct forum for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Thx Andy, now I know that for later :D